# Concatenation while inserting data in php using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data in a table, while developing the path of image I want to concatenate the path like

```
$location="/images/";
```

and file name  is as:

```
$image_title= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

and for insertion I am using the query:

```
$insertingdata="INSERT INTO product (productname, prodetails, imgurl) VALUES ('$title', '$details', '$location'.'$image_title')";
```

Any solution for this problem or someway better to do this?

Comment: I do not get your problem as such. But, closest is to concatenate both that values into a variable and pass that to the DB.

Comment: what is the exact error that you are getting here?

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of construction full query string

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do,

```
 $fullPath = $location.$imageTitle;
 $insertingdata="INSERT INTO product (productname, prodetails, imgurl) VALUES ('$title', '$details', '$fullPath');";
```

Comment: here it do not accept the path as:
$location="..\images\";
it produces the error for ending "\".

Comment: Well you never said that in your question. What is your error?

Comment: Because you need to escape the slashes, so you need to do \\images\\

Comment: But WHAT produces the error. What is the error? MySQL, PHP?

Comment: it do inserts url as:
..imagesDSC02220.JPG
whereas I want it to be inserted as:
..\images\DSC02220.JPG

Comment: Then you need to put $fullpath in mysqi escape string http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php (I am assuming you are using mysqli, if not you should be)

Comment: yup I am using mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

$insertingdata="INSERT INTO product (productname, prodetails, imgurl) VALUES ('$title', '$details', ".mysql_real_escape_string($location.$image_title).")";

Answer (score 0):

```
$insertingdata="INSERT INTO product (productname, prodetails, imgurl) VALUES ('$title', '$details', '".$location.$image_title."')";
```

You should do this, or insert them like Antony says.
If you do `'$location'.'$image_title'` it inserts it like:

`'..\images\'.'filename.ext'` instead of `'..\images\filename.ext'`

And i always use `/` instead of `\` Don't know if that's also a problem.

Comment: I am using this address "..\images\filename.ext" and perfectly displays the results when there is a need to show the images and if i do it like "../images/filename.ext" it simply says "Preview not available" as an alt atribute instead of displaying the image.

Comment: @WaqasSajid Okay... But did the other solution work or didn't you try it yet?